# iPad breaks button text into two separate lines

Tags: css, ipad

The following code works fine everywhere apart from the iPad where the text inside the button is broken in two lines:

```
.sign_up {
  background: url('../images/submit_button.png') no-repeat 0 0;
  border: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 12px;
  width: 110px;
  height: 34px;
}
```

the sign_up class has been given to the button element which contains "add others" as text.

However, on the iPad, "others" ends up being on the second line.

Comment: now used to white-space:nowrap; in your sign_up class

Answer (score 1):

Reset the iPad button default style with -

```
button, input[type="button"], input[type="reset"], input[type="submit"] { -webkit-appearance: button; cursor: pointer; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in css `white-space:nowrap;`